# Representing Multivalued attribute in a subclass in ERD

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, erd

The database model I am working on requires me to allow for a scenario where a specific book can be co-written by one or more author. I want to know if I am representing the model properly with the use of multi-valued attribute for author(s), as shown in my diagram:

[image]

I also used a generalized hierarchy for Items which may be in a book, eBook or magazine format. I would also love to know if this is a reasonable or redundant use of generalization hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You are using one among several Extended ERD notation (EERD) and these modeling techniques are not standardized. So it depends also of your modeling notation.

But as far as I can tell:

The double-ellipse around author indeed indicates that it's a multivalued attribute. So your notation is fine.  However,  multivalued attributes are not compatible with the first normal forml (1NF). It may therefore be worth to consider `author` as a separate entity, especially if you want to differentiate several authors with the same name, or efficiently search by author.

The use of the [disjoint subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13359259/3723423) where an `Item` can either be a `Book`, an `eBook` or a `Magazine` is fine:

- `Book`, `eBook` and `Magazine` inherit `Item`'s attributes and there seem to be no redundancy.
- `ISBN` is used by two subclasses of the three.  This is fine as well: if you'd move it to Item,  magazines, which have a different identifier, would also inherit it.
- Alternatively,  you could consider having a Book entity that is subclassed into an eBook and a `paperBook` category if you want to remove this redundancy?

Comment: Much appreciated Christophe.  Pretty helpful getting a second opinion on my model. Your alternative is a great idea. Will give a go at it.